# iOS Safari shows blank <option> text despite setting HTMLOptionElement.label (but it works in Chrome), why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulties updating the value of an options (dropdown) HTML element.

What I'm trying to do is iterate over serveral dropdown values which are in an array, and update de value and label:

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var answers = [1,2,3]

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    options[i + 1].value = answers[i];
    options[i + 1].label = answers[i];
    options[i + 1].selected = false;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
</div>
```

But after the code has run thedropdown looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this? The shown code is actually working on other browsers.

———-

The Safari DOM inspector shows the `<option>`'s `label=""` and `value=""` attributes are correctly set. Curious...

[image]

Comment: Use your debugger to see what every element of `q.answers` looks like. I'll bet it's an empty string or `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe a noob question but how can I use the debugger in my mobile Safari?

Comment: `options[i + 1]` <-- Why are you using `+1`? Also, your code won't work as-expected if `options.length != q.answers.length` (`+/-1` of course).

Comment: [You need to use macOS Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/), if you don't have a physical Mac (MacBook, MacBookPro, Mac Mini, iMac, Mac Studio, nor Mac Pro) then you're SOL.

Comment: I want one empty option, and three options filled with the 3 answer options from the array. But the code is working fine in Chrome etc. So I'm trying to find out why it does not update on Safari on mobile.

Comment: I can take a look using iOS Safari and my Mac's Web Inspector, but you still haven't provided enough details for us to reproduce the issue, so you will need to post a link to a CodePen or JSFiddle (or whatever) example that reproduces the issue. Also, what version of iOS Safari are you using?

Comment: @Dai I added a code snippet. When on Chrome this works, but when I view the dropdown on Safari I dont see 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I’ve posted a screenshot of what Safari says.

Comment: I found the problem: Safari doesn't support `<option label="">` until Safari 15.6 which only came out a month ago: https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_option_label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that (as of September 2022) all versions of Safari prior to 15.6 do not display the text of the `HTMLOptionElement.label` property on-screen. (this affects [both macOS Safari and iOS Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_option_label), and Safari 15.6 was only released a few weeks ago).

- Instead, just change `.label = answers[i]` to `.textContent = answers[i]`, as below.
- Also, you don't need to set `.selected = false` on every `HTMLOptionElement` *unless* its owner `<select>` has `<select multiple="multiple">` (which you don't), so just set `options[i].closest('select').selectedIndex = 0;` to reset selection to the first `<option>`.

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var answers = [1,2,3]

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    const a = answers[i].toString();
    const o = options[i+1];

    o.value       = a;
    o.label       = a; // <-- Safari (prior to v15.6) ignores .label and uses .textContent instead, so set both properties.
    o.textContent = a;

    const select = o.closest('select');
    if( select && select.selectedIndex !== 0 ) select.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
</div>
```

#### Screenshot proof (after applying fix):

| Chrome 105 on Windows | iPad Safari 15.1 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Thanks a lot for you investigation and solution. This works!! Side question: does it really matter to just put all elements on '.selected = false;'? It wouldn't really impact performance right?

Comment: @WardBrink Correct, it does not impact performance. The main reason I don't like using `.selected = false;` on every element is because it makes _the developer's intention_ unclear (at least without adding an explanatory comment). Also, using `document.getElementsByTagName('option');` is probably a bad idea because you'll pull-in **all** `<option>` elements, including from `<datalist>` and `<optgroup>` (so not just from `<select>` elements). I think you should iterate over each `<select>` element, _then_ each child `<option>` instead.

Comment: Haha I was trying to but did not have enough point yet, but now I have. Will upvote!

Comment: Looks like this is still happening as of Safari iOS 16.2

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I tested it just now on iPad OS 16.3.1 and it works fine for me. Can you post a screenshot of what you’re seeing?

Comment: @Dai [here's a screenshot from my iPhone with iOS 16.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsJMx.png). Maybe it was fixed after 16.2. You can see for yourself the webpage I'm testing here: https://syscalls.mebeim.net (before I update it with the correct code later today). Currently my `<option>` elements have a `label` and no `.textContent` set. On iOS safari I see the options as blank, but on macOS Safari they look fine.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I can reproduce that on my iPad running 16.3.1. I'm looking at your `index.js` and I see that you're not setting `opt.value`, only `opt.label`. Presumably, setting `.value` or `.textContent` to some nonempty string should nudge iOS Safari into doing the right thing.

Comment: @Dai having a `value` set does not seem to matter. I still see blank options. Here's a test page I just created with both `label` and `value`, same result: https://mebeim.altervista.org/dev/test/option-ios.html Safari really wants a `.textContent` set.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Huh, weird - no idea, sorry :/ - All I can suggest [is filing a Webkit bug](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: @Dai yeah no problem. I just wanted to point that out to you (and to future readers). At the end of the day your suggestion works.